# raiz quadrada "perfeita" em python e identificar o resto:

Tags: python, python-3.x

É para python 3:

O que eu estou querendo fazer é mostrar o resto de uma conta de raiz quadrada que só aceita o maior número inteiro possível como resposta.
Por exemplo:

```
import math

x=math.sqrt(87)

print(x)
```

Esse código retorna 9.327379053088816, eu quero que meu código retorne apenas **9** e me mostre o resto que nesse caso seria **6**(os número em negrito são os que eu quero aparecendo) já que 9²=81 e 87-81=6...seria +- o que a função % + a função// fazem na divisão. Só que agora na raiz quadrada.

Eu acho que eu expliquei o que eu quero o melhor que eu pude, alguém pode me ajudar nesse pedido doido XD?

Comment: seria algo tipo: `radicando = 87` `x = math.sqrt(radicando)` `z = radicando - (2*math.int(x))` `print(z)`?

Comment: no caso errei aqui, muda a variável z para `z = math.int(x) * math.int(x)` para poder pegar o quadrado da raiz, foi maus.

Comment: Desculpe, Armando esse seu código não funcionou, o código que eu queria era o que o Anderson sugeriu ali embaixo, obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: opa, @Matheus, soh queria ajudar mesmo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basta utilizar os operadores matemáticos `//` para obter a divisão inteira e `%` para obter o resto da divisão. Veja o exemplo:

```
import math

value = 87
sqrt = math.sqrt(value) # 9.327379053088816

div = value // sqrt  # 87 // 9.327379053088816 = 9
mod = value % div    # 87 % 9 = 6

print(div, mod)
```

Alternativamente você pode fazer algo como:

```
print(divmod(value, int(math.sqrt(value))))
```

Que é, para efeitos práticos, equivalente ao código anterior.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/xgLpFL).

Comment: Funcionou. Eu já tinha achado outra maneira de fazer isso, mas a sua maneira é muito mais rápida e limpa, muito obrigado

Answer (score 5):

A [resposta do colega Anderson](/a/232464/70) já levou meu +1, mas só para complementar segue uma alternativa sem uso do módulo:

```
import math

value = 87

sqrt = int(math.sqrt(value))
remainder = value - (sqrt * sqrt)


print(sqrt, remainder)
```

Nesta versão estamos arredondando a raiz (`sqrt`) e calculando o resto "primitivamente", fazendo a subtração da raiz perfeita do valor original (similar ao método usado pelo colega Armando nos comentários da pergunta).

> Veja funcionando no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/t619An).